# How to change table of contents left captions from chinese to english

Tags: table-of-contents, chinese

Below are my codes I want to change the Chinese parts in the latex file to English. Especially for the table of contents.

Here sample files for your testing

```
https://www.overleaf.com/4133627834ctfqvdzvszbt#8aab90

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMN6z.png
```

Comment: all those fixed texts are English by default so in code you have not shown you have set them to Chinese.

Comment: the problem is with the final file when it loads i see the chinese part on the table of contents as shown in the attached image which i wish to change

Comment: But you have shown code that no one can use as it includes files you have not shown and you are asking about why the generated texts are in Chinese but nothing in the code you have shown selects Chinese so they would all be English. Make a small self contained file that shows the problem that people can run and test answers. As it is it is impossible to guess. You have done _something_ to make the table of contents be Chinese and are asking how to change that code, but without saying what you have done.

Comment: Please instead of code snippets, always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that can be used to reproduce the problem. Such a MWE usually starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: i have added some more codes for your use. i hope this proves more helpful

Comment: Are the `UJS-PhD-thesis` document class files available online? If so, where?

Comment: You can access the UJS-PhD-thesis document class file below:
https://www.overleaf.com/4133627834ctfqvdzvszbt#8aab90